# How to design for Android apps ever-changing screen dimensions

Tags: android, xml

I'm a web designer by nature, accustomed to changing resolutions and font sizes, but I'm unsure how to design for the Android platform without knowledge of screen sizes, especially when the screen rotates from portrait mode to landscape.

Should I just do generic things that tile, or is there a way to design things of static size?

By this, I mean for the GUI and graphics, not element nodes of the XML.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Found the answer, in case future developers are wondering.